# JUnit, Comparing Objects

Tags: java, regex, unit-testing, testing, junit

I'm learning JUnit, I know that assertEquals() invokes the equals() method to compare objects... so why the following test that compares two regex Pattern objects does not pass?

```
@Test
public void testTwoCompiledPattern()
{   
    assertEquals(Pattern.compile("test"), Pattern.compile("test"));
}
```

This one passes instead:

```
@Test
public void testTwoCompiledPattern()
{   
    assertEquals(Pattern.compile("test").toString(), Pattern.compile("test").toString());
}
```

Comment: I think there is something going wrong. My first think we shouldn't check that correct Pattern is created. I would rather check string that passed to pattern (if your code generates them). Could you share case what are you checking in this particular test?

Comment: +1. That was only a test to learn JUnit, in real situations I would check strings as you suggested.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its because when you call the toString() method, both returns the "test" string because the Pattern class overrides it. But if you compare just the Pattern objects, they are 2 different objects, hence one is not equal to the other one, even though they have the same state.

The equals method checks for reference equality.

Comment: Thanks. Which are the best practices to compare objects in these cases? toString()?

Comment: Well, you probably hate when someone says this but "it depends". You would have to check the Java API to see which methods might help you achieve what you want. In the Pattern class case, there is a method called pattern() that returns the String regex in which the Pattern object was compiled, in this case, "test" and then you can compare them. ( pattern() does the same as toString() though in this case ).  But when you have classes of your own you can override the equals method to implement you're own object equality, but there are certain rules you must obey.

Answer (score 1):

.equals of Pattern object checks if both are referring to same object.

however String.equals method checks if both string are identical(not object reference comparison)

ie why 2nd one passed.

Comment: Thanks. Simple Java question: in general how do I know when the equals() method checks for objects reference or content?

Comment: Generally you don't know. The only way is to read JavaDoc for method/class, which should describe internal behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The `equals()` method compares the hash code of the two objects. In the fomer case there are two different objects that have different hash codes so the test fails. In the latter case, there are two strings, "test", that will have same hash code so the test passes.

Comment: not really, 2 objects who are equal must give the same hashcode, BUT if they have the same hashcode they are not required to be equal. So the equals method compares reference value equality, not hashcode equality. In the case of strings if you have 2 string references with the same value, they are implicitly pointing at the same string object, thats why they are equal.